# Create a Project in the defined workspace using Rally Java RestAPI

Tags: java, rally

I’m trying to use the Rally Java REST API - https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava. How can I create a new project in my defined workspace? I am not able to find anything useful, any help would be much appreciated.

By referring the documentation, i tried the below code, but the project is not created in the Rally

```
RallyRestApi rallyService = new RallyRestApi(new URI(rallyURL), userName, password);
rallyService.setApplicationName("RallyRestExample");
rallyService.setWsapiVersion("v2.0");

JsonObject newProject = new JsonObject();
newProject.addProperty("Name", "Rally Rest Sample");
newProject.addProperty("Description", "Java Rally Rest API");
newProject.addProperty("State", "Open");
newProject.addProperty("Owner", "Karthi");
newProject.addProperty("Workspace", "/workspace/XXX");

CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("Project", newProject);
CreateResponse createResponse = rallyService.create(createRequest);
```

Thanks
Karthi

Comment: I'm guessing createResponse.wasSuccessful() returns false?  You should be able to get some insight to what went wrong by inspecting the contents of the createResponse.getErrors() array..

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. Its working now, since i am logging with a particular user, I should not add the 'Owner' to the JsonObject . When i removed the owner, the project got created under the particular workspace

Answer (score 2):

There is a user guide in GitHub [here](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/wiki/User-Guide). This walks you through how to set up a project and how to use methods provided to you by the API.

There is also full API Documentation [here](http://rallytools.github.io/RallyRestToolkitForJava/).

On the GitHub page, it also gives you a link to the Web Services API documentation, but you will need a Rally login to view this.

- Create a new Java Project
- Make sure you have all the required jars (listed in the documentation) in the Java Project
- Add the rally-rest-api dependency into your pom.xml (steps listed in documentation)
- Instantiate a new RallyRestAPI object by using...

```java
RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"), "user@company.com", "password");
```

Then use `restApi`to use the provided methods from the documentation.

Comment: Zack, Thanks for your quick reply, I referred the documentation and tried to create the project, but still the project is not created. I have updated my original post with the code. Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: Did you include all the required jars and did you update you POM.xml file? What error are you getting?

Comment: I have included all jars, I am not using pom.xml, since I am not using maven (created a simple java main application). I am not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use the property `newProject.addProperty("Workspace", "/workspace/XXX");` and `newProject.addProperty("Owner", "Karthi");` with values like `"/workspace/XXX"` and  `"Karthi"`. Instead you need to provide it with the object ID of respective workspace and owner.